If $n=2,3\pmod{4}$, $G$ is a packable graph of order $n$ with size at most $n-2$ then it's a spanning subgraph of an almost self-complementary graph
Definitions:
Almost self-complementary graph
A graph $G$ is almost self-complementary if it's isomorphic to its complement $\overline{G}$ minus an edge.
Packable graph
A graph $G$ is packable if it is isomorphic to a subgraph of its complement.
Spanning subgraph
A graph $G$ is a spanning subgraph of a graph $H$, if it contains every vertex of $H$.
If $n=2,3\pmod{4}$, $G$ is a packable graph of order $n$ with size at most $n-2$ then it's a spanning subgraph of an almost self-complementary graph

I can't find a solution to this problem on the internet at all.
I am specialized in functional analysis, so I am not an expert in Graph Theory. So I don't even know where to start in this problem to be honest.

First, the $mod$ condition guarantee that it is possible to have a self-complementary graph (We easily check that there is no self-complimentary graph with $n=0,1(mod ;4)$). Now, what you need to show is that given a packable graph, we can add edges so that it becomes self-complementary. For that, keep in my that adding an edge to the graph means removing an edge to the complementary graph. You just need to find under which condition adding an edge will keep a graph packable (with the isomorphism remaining the same), then show that you can always find an edge satisfying this condition.

@caduk I don't really understand what you mean. The implication I need to prove is that if G is packable, then it's a spanning subgraph of an almost self-complementary graph. If n=2,3 (mod 4) then it's clear that if G is a spanning graph of something, then it's that of an almost self-complementary graph. The question here is how can I show that if G is packable, then it's a spanning subgraph of another graph?

"If n=2,3 (mod 4) then it's clear that if G is a spanning graph of something, then it's that of an almost self-complementary graph" Why is it clear, it is not necessarily true, every graph is a spanning subgraph of something (itself for example). "how can I show that if G is packable, then it's a spanning subgraph of another graph" Same, this is a trivial statement.

I think you are mixing two theorems: I have a reference in the literature that says that a graph of order $n$ and size $n-2$ is packable (this does not refer to almost self-complementary graphs), and I think the following result is true: If $G$ is a packable graph (no matter its size), then it is a spanning subgraph of an almost self-complementary graph.
